# How to reference the PK of a newly inserted row

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a query where a record gets added to the table channels. Each record there is then assigned a channelID which is the PK for the table, and auto increments. After a record is added to the channel table I want to insert strings associate with that record into another table called channel keywords. My problem is that I also need to pass in the channelID that created in the previous query as a parameter for the insert statement for the channelskeywords table, but I am not quite sure how to do this.

```
    IF @matchBy ='title'
    BEGIN
    insert into channels
    (userID,matchTitle,matchTitleAbstract, fromMyPage)
    values
    (@userID,1,0,@fromMyPage)


    END 

    IF @matchBy ='TitleAbstract'
    insert into channels
    (userID,matchTitle,matchTitleAbstract, fromMyPage)
    values
    (@userID,0,1,@fromMyPage)
    BEGIN

    IF (NULLIF(@keyword1, '')) IS NOT NULL
    insert into channelsKeywords
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
BEGIN
    -- be sure to declare this same scope as the one whol will be using the value
    DECLARE @CNT INT

    insert into channels (userID,matchTitle,matchTitleAbstract, fromMyPage)
    values (@userID,1,0,@fromMyPage)

    SET @CNT = Scope_Identity()  -- holds the value of the inserted ID

END
```

Additional Information:

- `@@IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes. You need to **be careful** here, since it's across scopes. You could get a value from a trigger, instead of your current statement.
- `SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope. Generally what you want to use.
- `IDENT_CURRENT` returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope. This lets you specify which table you want the value from, in case the two above aren't quite what you need (very rare).

**[See also here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)**

Comment: That did the trick, thanks for the help and the additional info!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the id by

```
Select Scope_Identity()
```

ie:

```
insert into channels 
(userID,matchTitle,matchTitleAbstract, fromMyPage) 
values 
(@userID,1,0,@fromMyPage) 
select @ChannelID = Scope_Identity()
```